# Анимационные SVG пути с прерывистыми частями

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, css-animation

На примере слева путь является постоянным (т.е. нет внутри еще одной команды `м`), следовательно, отрезки пути тянутся один за другим.

В примере справа путь является прерывистым (т.е. содержит дополнительные команды `м`), что позволяет рисовать  все сегменты одновременно.

Как я могу сделать так, чтобы сегменты в примере справа рисовались один за другим?

То есть, вторая строка, начинается только тогда, когда  верхняя строка  закончена, вместо  одновременного рисования,  как сейчас.

```html
<svg width="220px" height="100px" viewBox="-10 -10 240 120">
<style>
path{stroke-dasharray:500;stroke-dashoffset:500;fill:none;stroke:#000;stroke-width:6px;animation:draw 5s linear infinite;}
@keyframes draw{to{stroke-dashoffset:0;}}
</style>
  <path d="m0,0 h60 v60 h-60 z" />
  <path d="m120,0 h60 m-60,20 h60 m-60,20 h60 m-60,20 h60 m-60,20" />
</svg>
```

Comment: ассоциация:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39896469/animating-svg-paths-with-discontinuous-parts/39896916#39896916

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот подход с использованием нескольких элементов пути, и с помощью `animation-delay`, сделано так, что линии рисуются одна за другой:

```css
path{
  stroke-dasharray:10;
  stroke-dashoffset:10;
  fill:none;
  stroke:#000;
}
path:nth-child(1){animation:draw1 4s linear infinite}
path:nth-child(2){animation:draw2 4s linear infinite}
path:nth-child(3){animation:draw3 4s linear infinite}
path:nth-child(4){animation:draw4 4s linear infinite}
@keyframes draw1{
  20%,100%   {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
@keyframes draw2{
  20%    {stroke-dashoffset:10;}
  40%,100%   {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
@keyframes draw3{
  40%    {stroke-dashoffset:10;}
  60%,100%   {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
@keyframes draw4{
  60%    {stroke-dashoffset:10;}
  80%,100%   {stroke-dashoffset:0; }
}
```

```html
<svg width="220px" height="100px" viewBox="0 0 10 11">
  <path d="M0,1  h10" />
  <path d="M0,4  h10" />
  <path d="M0,7  h10" />
  <path d="M0,10 h10" />  
</svg>
```

[Источник](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39896916/7394871): Animating SVG paths with discontinuous parts
@web-tiki